# Listview selector is not working for some reason

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I put these line in /res/drawable/listview_main.xml layout: `android:listSelector="@drawable/seletor2"` and createad a selector (seletor in portuguese). But for some reason it didn't work and then I tried programmatically to call Listview selector. Again, no selector is showed when I click on item in my Listview (it stills transparent, no color). I don'know why this is happening. Also, I put `listview.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);`, in case of if I have background Drawable on my ListView. I need some help.

listview_main.xml

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shape2"  
            android:layout_weight="1"


            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:divider="@color/red"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/seletor2"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
                android:dividerHeight="2px"
         />
```

seletor2

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    static String DEFINITION = "definition";
    static String WORD = "word";
    static String FLAG = "flag";
    EditText editsearch;
    private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // Execute DownloadXML AsyncTask
        new DownloadXML().execute();
    }

    // DownloadXML AsyncTask
    private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.favicon);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Search Parse");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create the array
            worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            // Retrive nodes from the given website URL in XMLParser.class
            String xml = parser
                    .getXmlFromUrl("http://ecxmlparser.esy.es/br.xml");
            // Retrive DOM element
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

            try {
                // Locate the NodeList name
                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("vocabulary");
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    WorldPopulation map = new WorldPopulation();
                    map.setDefinition(parser.getValue(e, DEFINITION));
                    map.setWord(parser.getValue(e, WORD));
                    map.setFlag(parser.getValue(e, FLAG));

                    worldpopulationlist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            Collections.sort(worldpopulationlist, new Comparator<WorldPopulation>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(WorldPopulation lhs, WorldPopulation rhs) {
                    return lhs.getWord().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getWord());
                }
            });

            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    worldpopulationlist);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);


                WorldPopulation voc = (WorldPopulation) adapter.getItem(position);



                i.putExtra("definition", voc.getDefinition());
                // Pass word
                i.putExtra("word", voc.getWord());


                i.putExtra("flag", voc.getFlag());

                i.putExtra("position", position);
                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);

            }

        });



            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
            editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

            // Capture Text in EditText
            editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String text = editsearch.getText().toString()
                            .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    adapter.filter(text);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                        int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                        int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

ListViewAdapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;
    private ArrayList<WorldPopulation> arraylist;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        TextView word;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return worldpopulationlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return worldpopulationlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml

            holder.word = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.word);

            // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews

        holder.word.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getWord());

        // Set the results into ImageView

        // Listen for ListView Item Click
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data definition

                intent.putExtra("definition",
                        (worldpopulationlist.get(position).getDefinition()));
                // Pass all data word
                intent.putExtra("word",
                        (worldpopulationlist.get(position).getWord()));
                                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("flag",
                        (worldpopulationlist.get(position).getFlag()));
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        worldpopulationlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (WorldPopulation wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getWord().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing this line from your selector   <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

Comment: @SandeepShabd I removed this line and it doesn't work yet!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use this for selector

```
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Cause you dont need other states of items . and set drawSelector on top true.
And setOnItemClickListener() on Listview . Make sure the layout you are using in adapter to inflate its parent layout should not be clickable . Otherwise it will intercept the list OnItemClick and you will not see not get OnItemClick call from list view ..

Comment: I updated my post above. I did what you said and rewrote my selector and I setOnItemClickListener() on ListView. But it continues doesn't work. All itemsview is showed, clickable, but when I click on any item, no color red is displayed. I don't know why yet!

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution. I put this line in ListViewAdapter: `view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seletor2);` and now it works fine!